# How to adjust height of a Text Component if the text that fills it is unknown?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I get text from a server and when I get it I want to show it in a UI Text component. The problem comes when I see that when I create a Text component it have to have a fixed height and width. There is a way to the text know it own text and fix itself vertically or something like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After assigning a new text you can simply use the [`preferredHeight`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Text-preferredHeight.html) like e.g.

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textComponent;
    [TextArea] public string newText;

    [ContextMenu(nameof(ApplyText))]
    public void ApplyText()
    {
        textComponent.text = newText;

        var size = textComponent.rectTransform.sizeDelta;
        size.y = textComponent.preferredHeight;
        textComponent.rectTransform.sizeDelta = size;
    }
}
```

---

[image]

---

In order to make it grow only to the bottom you simply have to fix your pivot settings to `pivot` `y = 1`

You can also use the layout dropdown menu, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on according entry:

[image]

Comment: Thank you it work but, when the text height grows it does for both sides top and bottom and I would like to make it grows just for the bottom side to make the text scrollable. There is a way to do it?

Comment: @SmoggeR_js yes .. simply change your pivot settings - see update